# selectedLi not working while adding Li using JQuery

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, dropdown

i have two dropDowns on a view. `SessionDateSelect` will get its contents from DB and `SessionSelect` will get is content from Db based on `SessionDateSelect` selectedLi. everything works fine so far. but when i click on contents of the `SessionSelect` dropDown nothing works:
here is my code :

```
div id="SessionDateSelect">
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="btn-DateSelect" data-toggle="dropdown">انتخاب تاریخ شروع کلاس
            <span class="caret"></span></button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="dateList">
                @{
                   var dateCollection = Session["classDates"] as List<string>;
                    if (dateCollection != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var item1 in dateCollection)
                        {
                            <li><a id="@item1" href="#">@item1</a></li>
                        }
                    }
                }
            </ul>
    </div>
</div>


<div id="SessionSelect">
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="btn-SessionSelect" data-toggle="dropdown">انتخاب جلسه
            <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="classSessions">

        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is js codes :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                var selectedDate=null;
                $("#SessionDateSelect").find("li a").click(function() {
                    $('.selectedLi').removeClass('selectedLi');
                    $(this).addClass('selectedLi');
                    selectedDate = $('.dropdown-menu').find("li a.selectedLi").attr('id');
                    var attgrade1 = $('.dropdown-menu').find("li a.selectedLi").text();
                    $('#btn-DateSelect').html("تاریخ شروع دوره" + " " + attgrade1 + '<span class="caret"></span>');
                    if (selectedDate != null) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: '@Url.Action("GetSessions", "Main")',
                            type: 'POST',
                            traditional: true,
                            data: { 'date': selectedDate },
                            success: function (data) {
                                alert(data);
                                var mySelect = $('#classSessions');
                                for (var i = 1; i <= data; i++)
                                {
                                    mySelect.append(' <li><a id="' + i + '"href="#">' + i + '</a></li>');

                                }

                            }
                        });
                    }
                });

                var selectedSession;
                $("#SessionSelect").find("li a").click(function () {
                    alert('click');
                    $('.selectedLi').removeClass('selectedLi');
                    $(this).addClass('selectedLi');
                    selectedSession = $('.dropdown-menu').find("li a.selectedLi").attr('id');
                    var attgrade = $('.dropdown-menu').find("li a.selectedLi").text();
                    $('#btn-SessionSelect').html("جلسه شماره" + " " + attgrade + '<span class="caret"></span>');

                });



            </script>
```

Comment: You need [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to handle events on dynamically added elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks 'Stephen Muecke' 
changed the js code and everything works fine :

```
 var selectedSession;
            $("#classSessions").on('click', 'li', function() {
                var selected = $(this).text();
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("ActionName", "Controller")',
                    type: 'POST',
                    traditional: true,
                    data: {'sessionNumber': selected}
                    });

            });
```